# Unable to resolve dependency for 'com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:6.2.0.0'

Tags: android, gradle, admob, android-studio-3.0, inmobi

i am implementing Admob mediation in my application [details are here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation)
when i trying to add [inmobi](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/inmobi) in cause the below error for adding  `compile 'com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:6.2.0.0'`in gradle dependencies

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:6.2.0.0.

Could not resolve com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:6.2.0.0.
Required by:
    project :app
 > No cached version of com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:6.2.0.0 available for offline mode.
```

gradle file look like below

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2'
    compile('com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:5.3.0@aar') {
        transitive=true
    }
    compile 'com.google.ads.mediation:vungle:5.3.0.0'
    compile 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:6.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:6.2.0.0'
}
```

there is also option for manual integration [link for get the adapter file](https://bintray.com/google/mobile-ads-adapters-android/com.google.ads.mediation.inmobi/#files/com%2Fgoogle%2Fads%2Fmediation%2Finmobi%2F6.2.4.0) but there is no such adapter with same version

can any one explain how to resolve this.

Comment: are you using Android Studio 3.0 ?

Comment: yes,it's in Android Studio 3.0

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers added `allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}` ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it's already there

Comment: what a silly mistake by you is `compile 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:6.2.0'` not `6.2.0.0`

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel it's not a mistake please check the document,https://bintray.com/google/mobile-ads-adapters-android/com.google.ads.mediation.inmobi/#files/com%2Fgoogle%2Fads%2Fmediation%2Finmobi%2F6.2.4.0  also in link there is other version for adapter are available like 6.2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `Preferences` in Android Studio
2. Go to `Gradle` tab and **uncheck** "Offline work" if it is checked

   [image: Gradle Offline Work]
3. Check if your PC has active internet connectivity
4. Sync your project again & you are good to go!

Comment: not working,still same error  ` failed to resolve com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:6.2.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

The min version of InMobi adapter is 6.2.3 : [Link](https://bintray.com/google/mobile-ads-adapters-android/com.google.ads.mediation.inmobi)

Replace the gradle dependency to look something like this :

`compile 'com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:6.2.4.0'`

PS: 6.2.4 is backward compatible with 6.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the adapter and you can find the dependencies [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/inmobi#step_3_import_the_inmobi_sdk_and_adapter)

Also, try adding inmobi alone and take out vungle dependencies.